# How to get Net-SMTP-SSL work with Bugzilla in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: perl, ubuntu, ssl, bugzilla

I have installed Net-SMTP-SSL (/usr/bin/perl install-module.pl Net::SMTP::SSL) since I'd like to configure Bugzilla email with Gmail. I did't got any error. However, when I run './checksetup.pl --check-modules', I still get the result:

```
Checking for         Net-SMTP-SSL (v1.01)     not found
```

I also try to re-install it and I still get the same output. Here is my system information:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Bugzilla 4.4.6

Answer (score 2):

After having the same problem with Bugzilla recently, I ran across this rejected bug report:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=897355

It mentions that there are some dependencies that Bugzilla isn't installing, but doesn't say which ones.  So I just ran cpan and issued the upgrade command from the cpan console to upgrade all packages.  This went though and installed a few dependencies from various packages that it said were missing.  I didn't see which ones were related to the SMTP SSL package since it was installing stuff several levels deep in dependencies, but after running that and then running checksetup.pl in Bugzilla, the problem ***seemed*** to be fixed.  Warning: It did take quite a while to upgrade all packages, though.

That fixes the issue with Bugzilla not detecting properly, but unfortunately it seems there's a bug in Net::SMTP::SSL conflicting with one of it's own dependencies.  You'll get an error something like "Not a GLOB reference" if you try to run the package directly.  You can see it by running this after updating all of the packages:

```
perl -MNet::SMTP::SSL -wE 'say $Net::SMTP::SSL::VERSION'
```

If you get a version number returned then it's working, but I get an error and have seen other posts about it, too.  I haven't been able to fix this problem yet, but there's probably some combination of the SSL package and various versions of it's dependencies that actually works, just not the latest of each.  Otherwise, I would think there would be a known issue in Bugzilla release notes as they would have run across it during testing.

I haven't had time to do it and haven't seen that anyone else has either including the package maintainer, but I suppose you could find all of the dependencies for Net::SMTP:SSL and then one by one update the packages using something like:

```
cpan upgrade Net::SMTP::SSL
```

Then replace Net::SMTP::SSL with each of it's dependencies one at a time and test using the perl command above.  When it breaks, you'll know which package is conflicting.  You can then roll that package back to an earlier version and update all other dependencies and hopefully it will fix the issue.  It's definitely possible that no combination will work, though, and if that's the case, I'll be a little disappointed in Bugzilla's testing process.

You can find dependencies using various methods, but CPAN has one.  Here's a link to an article about how to create a perl script to use it: https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN::FindDependencies

Anyway, this may not solve your problem, but I hope it helps in tracking down the issue, and know that you are not alone.  If you do find out anything, please post it here.  I will do the same if I have more time to work on it later.